# 画像上に、文字を縁取りしたテキストを描画したい

Tags: php, imagemagick

画像上にテキストを描画して出力していますが、画像によってはテキストが見づらくなります。

#### やりたいこと

画像上にテキスト描画する際、文字を縁取りしたテキストを描画したいです。

**参考:**
[パワポで文字に縁取りしている例](https://nulljapan.jp/ppt-text-miyasuku/)

**コードイメージ:**

```
$im = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$text='画像に追加したいテキスト';
$im->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);
```

Comment: [ImagickDraw クラス](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/class.imagickdraw.php)の`setStrokeXxxx`が使えるのでは？ [テキストの描画設定に使用するImagickDrawクラスのメモ](http://malog-notes.blogspot.com/2014/01/imagickdraw.html) 他言語の例 [ImageMagick: 画像に縁取り付き文字列を書き込む](http://haraita9283.blog98.fc2.com/blog-entry-424.html), [imagemagick 文字列を画像化する際に縁取りをしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/202246) あるいはこちらとか。[ImageTTFTextで縁取り文字画像の動的生成](http://blog.livedoor.jp/friendly_rium/archives/51916364.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下ではストロークサイズを変えて文字列を重ね書きしています。

```php
<?php

$im = new Imagick('penguin.jpg');
$text='画像に追加したいテキスト';

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont('/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc');
$draw->setFontSize(32); 
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

// lower
$draw->setStrokeColor('#fff'); // white
$draw->setStrokeWidth(5);
$im->annotateImage($draw, 10, 200, 0, $text);

// upper
$draw->setStrokeColor('#000'); // black
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$im->annotateImage($draw, 10, 200, 0, $text);

$im->writeImage('annotate.jpg');
```

[image: annotate]

Comment: 期待通り、動作しました。枠線指定して一度描画するのかと思っていたのですが、ストロークサイズを変えて文字列を重ね書きすれば、やりたいことが実現できたのですね。大変参考になりました